# How does InputStream.read(byte[]) work?

Tags: java, fileinputstream, zipinputstream

I'm trying to unzip a zip folder, I have problem understand how the `ZipInputStream.read(byte[])` work. This code work just fine but I don't know if my file is bigger than the buffer I set how I'll operate.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
zipIs = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE_PATH));
while ((entry = zipIs.getNextEntry()) != null) {

        String entryName = File.separator + entry.getName();

        // Call file input stream
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(entryName);

        int len;
        // Write current entry
        while ((len = zipIs.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        fos.close();
      }
```

I did read the doc but I find it confusing, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have problem understand how the `ZipInputStream.read(byte[])` work.

It is described in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-) for `InputStream.read(bytes[])`:

> This code work just fine but i don't know if my file is bigger than the buffer i set how i'll operate.

That is what the loop is for.

```
    while ((len = zipIs.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
```

It reads one buffer at a time, setting `len` to the number of bytes read, until the `read` call returns zero (or less).  Each buffer-full is written using `len` to say how many bytes to write, and then it repeats ...

The `while ((a = call()) > 0) {` syntax is simply exploiting the fact that an assignment (e.g. `(a = call())`) is an expression whose value that is the value that was assigned to the variable.

Reading streams is one situation where this idiom is commonly used.  It is worth remembering it.